# Python UART between 2 Raspberry Pis

Tags: python, linux, uart, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send strings between two Raspberry Pis via UART. So far, one Pi is able to transmit a string and the second pi is only able to receive. I'm trying send a "command" from one Pi to the other, then the second Pi will receive the "command" and then send "sensor data" back to the first Pi. However, this doesn't seem to work. I'm unable to both send and receive data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Raspberry Pi that is sending the command:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyAMA0',\
    baudrate = 115200,\
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,\
    timeout = 0)

dat = ''

while True:
    #asks user for input
    command = raw_input()
    #terminates command with null
    ser.write(command + '\0')

    #reads data per char
    for c in ser.read():
        #appends string
        dat += c
        #terminates at null char
        if c == '\0':
            print(dat)
            dat = ''
            break
ser.close()
```

This RPi that receives command and then sends sensor data:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    '/dev/ttyAMA0' ,\
    baudrate = 115200 ,\
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS ,\
    timeout = 0)

dat = ''
sen1 = 'sen1\x00'
sen2 = 'sen2\x00'
com1 = 'hello'
com2 = 'this thing works!'
com3 = 'error!'

while True:

    #reads data per char
    for c in ser.read():
    #appends string
    dat += c
    #terminates at null char
    if c == '\0':
        #decides which sensor to choose
        if dat == sen1:
            print(com1)
            ser.write(com1 + '\0')
            dat = ''
            break
        elif dat == sen2:
            print(com2)
            ser.write(com2 + '\0')
            dat = ''
            break
        else:
            print(com3)
            ser.write(com3 + '\0')
            dat = ''         

ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause is most likely your zero timeout. You've set `read()` to non-blocking as a result, so your sender Pi's `for` loops will most likely read nothing (or only a byte) and will terminate before everything's arrived. Also iterating over `ser.read()` doesn't really make sense since it returns only a byte anyway by default.

Increase timeout to some non-zero value.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    '/dev/ttyAMA0' ,\
    baudrate = 115200 ,\
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS ,\
    timeout = 0.1)
```

Assuming you want the response to a command received, before another command is sent, this should work for the sender:

```
while True:
    #asks user for input
    command = raw_input()
    #terminates command with null
    ser.write(command + '\0')

    dat = []
    lastRead = time.time()
    while time.time() - lastRead < 0.1:
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            dat.append(ser.read())
            lastRead = time.time()
    if dat and (dat[-1] == '\0'):
        print(''.join(dat[:-1]))
```

If 100ms or more passes before another byte is available, the while loop breaks and the last received byte is checked to know if its a null byte. Something similar should work for your receiver:

```
while True:
    dat = []
    lastRead = time.time()
    while time.time() - lastRead < 0.1:
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            dat.append(ser.read())
            lastRead = time.time()
    dat = ''.join(dat)
    # begin your comparisons here
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately your code did not work for me.

Comment: inter_byte_timeout would not compile. After a quick google search, I found interCharTimeout, which is suppose to do the same thing. After that change the program compiled, but it didn't solve my problem. When I enter a command "sen1" on the first Pi, the 2nd Pi (the receiver) doesn't send "sensor data" back to it. Strangely enough, after I enter one command it won't receive a second command. I know this because I ask the 2nd Pi (receiver) to print everything it receives a command from the first Pi.